# Why different predicate interfaces n JAVA 8?

Tags: java, interface, predicate, functional-interface

In Java 8 different predicate interfaces (ex. DoublePredicate, LongPredicate, IntPredicate, etc.) are provided. Now if you are going to implement the interface and write your own code in it, what is the advantage of having different predicate interfaces ? why not just one predicate interface ?

Comment: A more interesting question would by by do some primitive types and not others. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey actually it is why not BooleanStream,CharStream .... ? Brian said some where that it would increase the footprint of the JDK for APIs that a rarely use.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi while it is probably the reason, I don't image that compressed class files which are never used increase the footprint that much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The point of these specialized predicate interfaces is to avoid unnecessary [auto-(un)boxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) when you are working with primitives.

For example, if you need to use a `Predicate` that works on `int` values you can use `IntPredicate` with which you can pass an `int` directly to the `test(...)` method, instead of a `Predicate<Integer>` which requires boxing to an `Integer` object.

Note that in Java, it is not possible to use primitive types as type arguments (so, `Predicate<int>` is not allowed).

Answer (score 10):

These different interfaces exist for performance reasons.

Because `generics` don't allow primitive types (so far) and they require boxing, the API provides specialisation for primitives so you avoid the cost of boxing and unboxing.

Answer (score 4):

There are not just `Predicates` but also other functional interfaces with type-specific variants. The reason is, the support *primitive* types.

While the general version could be used with *object* types (including `Double`, `Long`, etc), there is no way for using primitives with generics. I.e.

```
Predicate<int> p; //does not compile
```

For example, the `IntStream` operates on `int` and not on `Integer`, but you can't use Object-typed Functional Interfaces on `int` values, so you need int-specific variants of the functional interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

These specialized predicate interfaces are provided to support primitive data type like int or float without autoboxing. Without them we have to convert our int data to Integer Object to use in Predicate interface.

http://codedestine.com/java-8-predicate-interface/

Comment: **Just a small correction:** there are no specialized functional interfaces for the `float` data type. IMHO, wrappers for `int`, `long` and `double` are available, but that's it.